# Removing substring with regex

Tags: python, string

I need to write a regex to extract the amount at the end from the below string

**Input:**   `Total: 4.00 4,123.00`

The **output** should like: `Total: 4,123.00`

That means I need to remove '4.00' with it.

my `python` code:

```
import re
text = 'Total: 4.00 4,123.00'

m = re.search('4.00 (.+?)$', text)
if m:
    found = m.group(1)
    print(found)
```

But this regex removes `Total:`  too. How can I fix it?

Comment: `found = f'Total: {m.group(1)}'`. However, the regex is not good, you probably want `re.search(r'Total:.* (\S+)', text)`

Comment: actually the `Total` isn't a fixed word. it may also be `Sum` or any others. I just need to find `4.00` from the string and remove it.

Comment: So that `4.00` is _always_ `4.00` and never, say, `3.00`?

Comment: Really, then just use `text = text.replace(' 4.00', '')`

Comment: Maybe you can use re.sub and replace with group 1 https://regex101.com/r/E72sgn/1 `print(re.sub(r"(\w:)\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b", r"\1", r"Total: 4.00 4,123.00"))`

Comment: thanks a lot, @Thefourthbird . I needed it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match a word char and a `:` in group 1, and match optional spaces and the digits after it. In the replacement using group 1.

```
(\w:)\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b
```

- `(\w:)` Capture **group 1** to match a word character and `:`
- `\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b` Match optional whitespace chars and 1+ digits with optional decimal part.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vZj6K8/1)

Example

```
import re

s = r"Total: 4.00 4,123.00"
pattern = r"(\w:)\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b"
print(re.sub(pattern, r"\1", s))
```

Output

```
Total: 4,123.00
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just use split here and avoid regex:

```py
inp = "Total: 4.00 4,123.00"
parts = inp.split()
output = parts[0] + ' ' + parts[2]
print(output)  # Total: 4,123.00
```

Comment: Might fail if the first part ("Total" here) is two words, but could use `rsplit` with limit.